# Execute Python with PHP

Tags: php, python

I try to execute this PHP command :

```
 $result = exec("sudo python /home/pi/test.py",$output, $ret);
 var_dump($result);
 echo "<br>";
 var_dump($output);
 echo "<br>";
 var_dump($ret);
```

This command works perfectly on a Linux Terminal but with the PHP it doesn't work.

Here the result on the PHP page :

```
string(0)
array(0) { }
int(9)
```

I verified the process with `ps -ef`, nothing appears.

Comment: Are you executing this in a web browser? If so, does apache (the likely user executing the php) have sudo rights without password?

Comment: The code above is probably executed by the user `www-data` or something similar (varies between distributions) - is that user authorized to perform `sudo`? Edit: @kainaw beat me by literally 5 seconds :)

Comment: @kainaw Yes i execute this with a web browser.

Already done, I modified the file /etc/sudoers by adding this line :

www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

Comment: @Bacara While that fixes your error - it is a very bad thing to do. Now, every vulnerability in your web browser - even ones that nobody knows about yet, are allowed to attack your system as root without a password. You are begging to have your machine raped.

Comment: @kainaw Well for my example I'm working in local, but it's good to know all vulnerabilities in my script.

Comment: why you need tu use sudo command?

Comment: @efirvida to avoid all permissions problems

Comment: is better to give custom privilege to the user to use the commands you need than give the full root power as @kainaw says

Comment: @kainaw All right, I'll try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be help someone with the same problem.
I managed later to execute a Python script with this PHP code :

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('sudo /home/pi/test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

For the moment, I never succeed to execute this in background. I try those solutions :

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("sudo /home/pi/test.py >/dev/null &");

$command = escapeshellcmd("sudo /home/pi/test.py &");
```

My PHP page wait also the end of the process, but i don't want to.